# Issue with Spring Security w/ Azure AD & the redirect_uri behind a reverse proxy

Tags: spring, spring-security, azure-active-directory

I have been trawling through the internet in search of a solution to my problem which is the following -

We have a Spring boot application with Spring Security OAuth2 and Azure Active Directory integration to manage our external authentication. When we try to log in, the redirect_uri in the login URL is wrong.

Instead of the redirect_uri showing as it is defined in the application.yaml & Azure AD Portal like "&redirect_uri=https://10.10.10.10/v1/login/oauth2/code/", it's appearing as "&redirect_uri=http://10.10.10.10:8080/v1/login/oauth2/code/". As you can see, it's dropping the https scheme and adding on the port which results in an error logging in due to a redirect_uri mismatch. It's important to note that this works fine locally, however when deployed to an environment behind a reverse proxy, it doesn't work.

**What I have tried** -

Adding the following properties to application.yaml -

- server.forward-headers-strategy=NATIVE
- server.forward-headers-strategy=FRAMEWORK
- server.tomcat.internal-proxies=.*
- server.tomcat.remoteip.protocol-header=x-forwarded-proto
- server.tomcat.remoteip.remote-ip-header=x-forwarded-for

Adding this to the nginx config for the path -

```
      resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
      set $upstream_be application;
      proxy_pass http://$upstream_be:8080;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

None of this has worked unfortunately and the issue still persists. Any ideas anybody?

Relevant pom.xml versions: spring-boot, spring-security=2.4.5, all azure-spring dependencies=3.4.0

This also had worked fine before we upgraded our azure dependencies from 2.3.5 to 3.4.0.

Comment: Hi, I know that this is somewhat of an older issue now, but I am in the same situation you were, so I wanted to ask, if @Thomas Vitale's answer helped solve your problem or not. If not, were you ever able to solve your problem?

Comment: Hi @roblox99, I can say that his answer did indeed help our situation, along with the nginx changes in the original post. I had unfortunately also been doing something silly at the time where I wasn't loading our application via https, I was using http instead which made figuring out my original issue difficult.

Answer (score 1):

When the proxy applies the standard [RFC7239 "Forwarded Headers"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7239) like `X-Forwarded-Proto` and `X-Forwarded-Host`, then the redirect url should be correctly computed after applying the following two configurations. (I assume you're using Tomcat)

```
server.forward-headers-strategy=NATIVE
```

> "If the proxy adds the commonly used X-Forwarded-For and
> X-Forwarded-Proto headers, setting server.forward-headers-strategy to
> NATIVE is enough to support those."

```
server.tomcat.redirect-context-root=false
```

> If you are using Tomcat and terminating SSL at the proxy,
> server.tomcat.redirect-context-root should be set to false. This
> allows the X-Forwarded-Proto header to be honored before any redirects
> are performed.

How is the redirect URL defined in Spring Boot? The above configuration works if you use a placeholder for the base URL, for example `{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}`. In this way, the `{baseUrl}` placeholder is dynamically resolved by Spring Security differently depending on whether it's behind a proxy or not.

More info in the official documentation:

- [Spring Boot - Running Behind a Front-end Proxy Server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-behind-a-proxy-server)
- [Spring Security - Proxy Server Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#http-proxy-server)

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for taking time to respond.

You're correct in the assumption that we're using Tomcat. At the moment our redirect_uri is defined like so - 

`spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.redirect-uri: https://10.10.10.10/v1/login/oauth2/code/`

If I replace the first portion with {baseUrl} will it still resolve to that or would it resolve to localhost after those changes?